# Alter Downvote Cost/First Downvote On Answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation

As it currently stands, a downvote costs -1 rep, and gives the poster -2 rep. We all know this. However, I was wondering if there could be an adjustment to this to help balance out rep famers.

One upvote takes 5 downvotes to negate rep wise, making a +1/-4 answer still worth internet points.

There are a couple ways to approach this to make those easy +1 answers that don't benefit anybody (we all know these answers, the ones on question that need to be closed as dupes, etc).

Making the first upvote on an answer worth +5 rep instead of 10 would make downvotes hurt a little bit more, potentially making it not worth the FGITW approach for the +1/2 and repeat method.

Alternatively downvotes could be worth a little more negative, but I think the half rep first vote could be a simple deterrant to rep farmers.

A second upvote could be worth +15, so that if it really is a good answer, the rep balances back to +20. Or just keep it at +10.

Alternative idea: make upvotes worth less if the question if closed

Comment: Prove that rep farmers are actually a problem such that we have to revisit this calculation.  Right now this reads like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @Makoto that was just one example, sorry. It applies to any answer on a question that has been, or should be closed. I'm not sure how to compile statistics like that (hence the discussion tag you removed, not quite sure why you did that?) I'm of the mindset that it's a well known issue that poor content floods the site and an attributing factor is people spoon feeding them answers.

Comment: @makoto people quickly answering bad questions, somehow legitimising these questions existence is arguably a very common situation. Don't tell me you don't think they participate in keeping the flow of bad questions going.

Comment: It's only a problem when the bad questions don't get fixed or closed. but... that seems quite common, at least in the questions i come across daily.

Comment: @Felix: Bikeshedding has been a problem since forever. You are gravely mistaken if you believe tweaking imaginary internet points will magically fix it.

Comment: @Makoto is it not a step towards fixing it? It's obviously a complex answer, but not applying or trying to implement solutions because it's not the magical fix-all seems counter productive

Comment: @Makoto Darn, me and bikeshedding again. I'll be honest, the concrete effect of imaginary points is far too wide reaching for me to try and decide how it affects stuff. I do believe it has an influence on everything that actually happens on SO, as to how, when and why, I leave that to wiser people. My humble opinion is, I find there is some truth in the idea that some people are only after the points, and that there might be a way to make gaining these points more aligned with slowing bad questions.

Comment: In the end there is never going to be a good solution when you have people who are more interested in farming their daily quota than actually helping out.  I think I actually have more down votes casted than I do up votes. I love clicking into a bad question, seeing 3 upvotes knowing in 5 minutes it is going to be closed.

Comment: @epascarello what's the benefit in 'farming your daily quota' of downvotes exactly? There is no benefit to that. Except raise the quality of the side, incidentally helping people... (Or  I am not getting the point you are trying to make?)

Comment: No people farm their upvotes. People just upvoting for their + points blows up anything thtat tries to even out the - vs +

Comment: @epascarello OH .... Completely the opposite of how I got your point.then I do agree with you, yes. Although giving upvotes doesn't give the upvoter rep, so I am not sure there is anykind of 'quota' at play...  But the people who upvote undeserving posts are indeed hurting this site :/.

Answer (score 8):

If someone is actually posting lots of +1/-4 answers, and gaining rep from doing so, they will soon be answer banned.  Then they will stop doing that (because they can't post answers at all).  Hopefully, at some point before the answer ban, the system will warn them strenuously enough to change their behavior.

Given that this appears to be a solved problem, I'd prefer not to overcomplicate the existing rep system, which is currently very straightforward to understand.

Comment: Answer bans don't apply to people with large amounts of rep

Comment: @SterlingArcher: If they are accumulating "large amounts of rep" before getting banned, then the system is not working properly.

Comment: @Kevin The post ban system is in place to remove people providing universally *terrible* content, who *never* provide *any* content of value.  Additionally, it fails to account for the fact that some users will upvote bad content for a variety of reasons (pity, having low quality standards, not understanding the problems(s) with the post, etc.).  The post ban system is all right at accomplishing what it's attempting to address, the problem is that it's just not attempting to address this specific problem.

Comment: The result of this is that users often providing rather poor (but not clearly abusive) answers, or users that manage to post an acceptable answer every now and then (or perhaps just have one post on a super popular question) just aren't going to get post banned.

Comment: It's also a difference of opinion. these people often don't see what they're doing as wrong in any way. They see it as being very helpful, because they are in fact providing answers or at least trying to help people who need it but just aren't quite at the point where they can ask a decent or non-duplicate question.